# unable to get gridview textbox value when readonly is true

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

i have my gridviews itemtemplate tag

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TotalTime" SortExpression="TotalTime">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="TotalTime" readonly="true" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>                                            
        </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

on my button click  event i am trying to make the textbox readonly property to false and get the value , but it doesnt work for TotalTime textbox

```
    protected void BtnSaveAttendence_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow Gr in GridView1.Rows)
        {
         TextBox txt = (TextBox)(Gr.FindControl("TotalTime"));
         txt.ReadOnly = false;
        }
        int Rest = new int();
        object[] objAttnd = new object[8];
        foreach (GridViewRow GR in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            objAttnd[0] = 0;
            objAttnd[1] = ((Label)GR.FindControl("LblEMPNAME")).Text;
            objAttnd[2] = UserInfo.Company.CompanyID;
            objAttnd[3] = Common.Convert_MM_DD_YYYY(txtDate1.Text);
            objAttnd[4] =((TextBox)GR.FindControl("InTime")).Text;
            objAttnd[5] =((TextBox)GR.FindControl("OutTime")).Text;
            objAttnd[6] = ((TextBox)GR.FindControl("TotalTime")).Text;                
            objAttnd[7] = Convert.ToDecimal(((Label)GR.FindControl("LblEmpCode")).Text);
            foreach (GridViewRow Gr in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)(Gr.FindControl("TotalTime"));
                txt.ReadOnly = true;
            }

         Rest = objAttendance.InsertUpdateAttendenceDetailNew(objAttnd);
        }
        if (Rest == -1)
        {
            lblError.Text = "<div class='ErrorMsg'> Attendance details already added for Selected date !!</div>";
        }
    }
```

Plz tell me how to get the value

Comment: why do you not use RowCreated event to access these text box to enable/disable..

Comment: @NiranjanKala: i want to get the value of textbox in this click event !!

Comment: Why use a click event? A RowCommand event gives you information that relates to the row in the gridview in which the button was clicked. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @BenRobinson : my button is outside the gridview and when i click submit button all the rows of gridview should be inserted !!

Answer (score 0):

As far as Your code it will read only one value of the `Textbox` as you are making it `Readonly false` and reading value in the `Foreach` loop then inside that `Foreach` loop itself you are having another `Foreach` loop that finds the `Textbox`  and makes `Readonly true` so take that `ForEach` loop out and alter your code like,

```
protected void BtnSaveAttendence_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow Gr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
     TextBox txt = (TextBox)(Gr.FindControl("TotalTime"));
     txt.ReadOnly = false;
    }
    int Rest = new int();
    object[] objAttnd = new object[8];
    foreach (GridViewRow GR in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        objAttnd[0] = 0;
        objAttnd[1] = ((Label)GR.FindControl("LblEMPNAME")).Text;
        objAttnd[2] = UserInfo.Company.CompanyID;
        objAttnd[3] = Common.Convert_MM_DD_YYYY(txtDate1.Text);
        objAttnd[4] =((TextBox)GR.FindControl("InTime")).Text;
        objAttnd[5] =((TextBox)GR.FindControl("OutTime")).Text;
        objAttnd[6] = ((TextBox)GR.FindControl("TotalTime")).Text;                
        objAttnd[7] = Convert.ToDecimal(((Label)GR.FindControl("LblEmpCode")).Text);
      /*ForEach from Here to*/

     Rest = objAttendance.InsertUpdateAttendenceDetailNew(objAttnd);
    }
  /*===>here*/
    foreach (GridViewRow Gr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)(Gr.FindControl("TotalTime"));
        txt.ReadOnly = true;
    }
    if (Rest == -1)
    {
        lblError.Text = "<div class='ErrorMsg'> Attendance details already added for Selected date !!</div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding readonly attribute from code behind like below:

```
TotalTime.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

And no need to set readonly to false before reading its value in code behind.